# Error when we are using \DefineBibliographyStrings . How to correct it?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

When I am trying to use `\DefineBibliographyStrings` with this codes,

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bibliography = {References},
  references = {Works Cited},
}
\begin{document}



This is by first title..
\cite{small}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

it is giving the following error,

> Package biblatex Error: File 'd.bbl' not created by biblatex.
>
> Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid.

How can I rectify this?

Comment: Please go back to the `biblatex` manual. Biblatex does **not** use `\bibliographystyle` or `\bibliography`, it uses a different syntax

Comment: Once the obsolete commands are removed and the proper `biblatex` commands added, you need to trash auxiliary files before starting compiling and enjoying `biblatex`.

Comment: Please have a look at [What to do to switch to biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) and [biblatex for idiots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864). As the others have rightfully pointed out `\bibliographystyle{plain}` is BibTeX-speak and `\bibliography` should come in the preamble of your document with `biblatex`.

Comment: no..I couldnt correct my file yet...@moewe

Comment: Have you read the links? Do you understand that you cannot use `\bibliographystyle{plain}` together with `biblatex`? If you want to use `biblatex` you need your document to look like the example in the links above.

Comment: Are there any news here? It is very unclear to me what exactly is happening here. Do you want to use `biblatex`? If so, please refer to the links above to see what a document ought to look like. If you just want to change certain strings while using traditional BibTeX styles, you will find other questions about that on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the above comments, and a request from @moewe.. I am posting this answer with a small error.
That is the numbering in the list of references is not in a propermanner,
But, for that refer [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280541/how-to-format-the-bibliography-while-we-are-using-works-cited-and-further-readin).

here are the corrected codes,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true,openany]{scrbook} % 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
\nocite{*}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@Book{bapat2013combinatorial,
 author = {Bapat, R. B.},
 title = {Combinatorial matrix theory and generalized inverses of matrices},
 publisher = {Springer},
 year = {2013},
 address = {New Delhi New York},
 isbn = {8132210522}
 }

@book{nashed1976generalized,
  title={Generalized Inverses and Applications: Proceedings of an Advanced Seminar on Generalized Inverses and Applications},
  author={Nashed, M.Z.},
  series={Academic Press rapid manuscript reproduction},
  url={https://books.google.co.in/books?id=YXbyQwAACAAJ},
  year={1976},
  publisher={Academic Press}
} 

@book{kesavan2014functional,
  title={Functional Analysis},
  author={Kesavan, S.},
  series={Texts and Readings in Mathematics},
  url={https://books.google.co.in/books?id=YXbyQwAACAAJ},
    year={2014},
  publisher={Hindustan Book Agency(India)}
  Number={52}
  isbn={978-93-80250-62-5}
} 

@article{mos,
author = {Moslehian},
title = {A Survey Of The Complemented Subspace Problem},
journal = {Trends in Mathematics,
Information Center for Mathematical Sciences},
year = {June, 2006},
volume = {9}
Number = {1}
Pages={91–98},
note = {tohbhhjhj appear},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle
%\input{tit.tex}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents


\chapter{A Unified Operator Theory of Generalized Inverses}

See this \cite{kesavan2014functional} gives [2] as the reference number, but I want that this has to be [1], since I am citing this as my first citation in my first page of my notes. 


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\printbibliography[title={Works cited},category=cited]% default title for `article` class: "References"
\printbibliography[title={Further Reading},notcategory=cited]


\end{document}
```

And the output is,

[image]

[image]