# How to format the bibliography while we are using works cited and further reading

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using the following codes for my notes..

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true,openany]{scrbook} % 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
\nocite{*}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@Book{bapat2013combinatorial,
 author = {Bapat, R. B.},
 title = {Combinatorial matrix theory and generalized inverses of matrices},
 publisher = {Springer},
 year = {2013},
 address = {New Delhi New York},
 isbn = {8132210522}
 }

@book{nashed1976generalized,
  title={Generalized Inverses and Applications: Proceedings of an Advanced Seminar on Generalized Inverses and Applications},
  author={Nashed, M.Z.},
  series={Academic Press rapid manuscript reproduction},
  url={https://books.google.co.in/books?id=YXbyQwAACAAJ},
  year={1976},
  publisher={Academic Press}
} 

@book{kesavan2014functional,
  title={Functional Analysis},
  author={Kesavan, S.},
  series={Texts and Readings in Mathematics},
  url={https://books.google.co.in/books?id=YXbyQwAACAAJ},
    year={2014},
  publisher={Hindustan Book Agency(India)}
  Number={52}
  isbn={978-93-80250-62-5}
} 

@article{mos,
author = {Moslehian},
title = {A Survey Of The Complemented Subspace Problem},
journal = {Trends in Mathematics,
Information Center for Mathematical Sciences},
year = {June, 2006},
volume = {9}
Number = {1}
Pages={91–98},
note = {tohbhhjhj appear},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle
%\input{tit.tex}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents


\chapter{A Unified Operator Theory of Generalized Inverses}

See this \cite{kesavan2014functional} gives [2] as the reference number, but I want that this has to be [1], since I am citing this as my first citation in my first page of my notes. 


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\printbibliography[title={Works cited},category=cited]% default title for `article` class: "References"
\printbibliography[title={Further Reading},notcategory=cited]


\end{document}
```

### Question:

1. I wish my "work cited" must give me the references list in the order whatever i am maintaining in my citation in my notes.
   That is, if I cite the `mos` in my first page is has to be the first reference in my work cited.
2. And in the `Further reading`, I should restart the numbering.
3. And I dont want the url for a book in my Reference list.

Here is my output,

### First page

[image]

### Works cited page.

[image]

Further reading page
--[image]

All are in distinct pages, to give minimal i am croping only the contents.

Comment: Can we infer from this post that your problem in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278647/35864 was resolved? If so please consider posting an answer there or deleting the question altogether.

Comment: @moewe As you have given in your comment. I have tried to go with biblatex.  I will add an answer there, if I resolved this problem. Because the numbering also must be corrected. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have the citations sorted as they appear in the text, you need the sorting option `sorting=none`.

If you have several bibliographies in a numeric style you should also listen to `biblatex`'s advice in the `.log` file and use `defernumbers=true`.

Your second bibliography then needs a `resetnumbers` to restart the numbering, I have also added `prefixnumbers={F}` so one can distinguish the further reading from the works cited with one glance.

```
\printbibliography[title={Further Reading},notcategory=cited,resetnumbers,prefixnumbers={F}]
```

Your `.bib` file was missing several commas (only the very last in an entry may be omitted) and threw several errors, I have changed that in the MWE

```
\documentclass{article} % 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\nocite{*}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{bapat2013combinatorial,
 author = {Bapat, R. B.},
 title = {Combinatorial matrix theory and generalized inverses of matrices},
 publisher = {Springer},
 year = {2013},
 address = {New Delhi New York},
 isbn = {8132210522},
 }

@book{nashed1976generalized,
  title={Generalized Inverses and Applications: Proceedings of an Advanced Seminar on Generalized Inverses and Applications},
  author={Nashed, M.Z.},
  series={Academic Press rapid manuscript reproduction},
  url={https://books.google.co.in/books?id=YXbyQwAACAAJ},
  year={1976},
  publisher={Academic Press},
} 

@book{kesavan2014functional,
  title={Functional Analysis},
  author={Kesavan, S.},
  series={Texts and Readings in Mathematics},
  url={https://books.google.co.in/books?id=YXbyQwAACAAJ},
    year={2014},
  publisher={Hindustan Book Agency (India)},
  Number={52},
  isbn={978-93-80250-62-5}
} 

@article{mos,
author = {Moslehian},
title = {A Survey Of The Complemented Subspace Problem},
journal = {Trends in Mathematics,
Information Center for Mathematical Sciences},
year = {June, 2006},
volume = {9},
Number = {1},
Pages={91–98},
note = {tohbhhjhj appear},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}
See this \cite{kesavan2014functional} gives [2] as the reference number, but I want that this has to be [1], since I am citing this as my first citation in my first page of my notes. 

\printbibliography[title={Works cited},category=cited]
\printbibliography[title={Further Reading},notcategory=cited,resetnumbers,prefixnumbers={F}]
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: How to neglect the url in @books-references. Is there any options to do that automatically??

Comment: @David See [Biblatex: Suppressing urldate does not work (\clearfield)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278890/35864) and its linked questions.

Answer (score 1):

First off all thanks to @moewe. here, I am posting the complete solution which helps others,

The codes are,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true,openany]{scrbook} % 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
\nocite{*}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{book}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{collection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{incollection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
}


\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@online{Bonline,
```

author = {BBBBonline, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
}

```
@collection{Ccollection,
    editor = {CCCCColletionEditor, C.},
    year = {2002},
    title = {Charlie},
    url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
    urldate = {2010-01-01},
}
@book{kesavan2014functional,
  title={Functional Analysis},
  author={Kesavan, S.},
  series={Texts and Readings in Mathematics},
  url={https://books.google.co.in/books?id=YXbyQwAACAAJ},
    year={2014},
  publisher={Hindustan Book Agency(India)}
  Number={52}
  isbn={978-93-80250-62-5}
} 

@article{mos,
author = {Moslehian},
title = {A Survey Of The Complemented Subspace Problem},
journal = {Trends in Mathematics,
Information Center for Mathematical Sciences},
year = {June, 2006},
volume = {9}
Number = {1}
Pages={91–98},
note = {tohbhhjhj appear},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle
%\input{tit.tex}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents


\chapter{A Unified Operator Theory of Generalized Inverses}

See this \cite{kesavan2014functional} gives [2] as the reference number, but I want that this has to be [1], since I am citing this as my first citation in my first page of my notes. 


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\printbibliography[title={Works cited},category=cited]% default title for `article` class: "References"
\printbibliography[title={Further Reading},notcategory=cited,resetnumbers,prefixnumbers={F}]


\end{document}
```

And the desired output is,(Note that, now the url's in @book field and @collection fields are not printing rather, @online prints the url as we want.

[image]

[image]